# VLookup in VBA is not working however it's working on cells

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

This is my function that to take an array with dates and return the hours per week according to an existing table in my Sheet `Eng_Availability_Report`. For me, it seems to be correct but VBA sends me a message with Error 1004. I used a `MsgBox` to return the weeknumber and the number actual exists in the range I'm looking for.

```
Public Function ReturnHoursPerWeek(Arr1() As Variant) As Variant

Dim Hours() As Double, k As Integer, WeekNumber As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook

k = 1
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Eng_Availability_Report")

If LBound(Arr1()) = UBound(Arr1()) Then
ReDim Hours(LBound(Arr1()))
    WeekNumber = Int(((Arr1(1, 1) - DateSerial(Year(Arr1(1, 1)), 1, 0)) + 6) / 7)
    MsgBox (" " & WeekNumber & " ")
        If WeekNumber > 0 And WeekNumber < 14 Then
            Hours(k) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(WeekNumber, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Eng_Availability_Report").Range("F6:G19"), 7, False)
        ElseIf WeekNumber > 14 And WeekNumber < 27 Then
            Hours(k) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(WeekNumber, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Eng_Availability_Report").Range("H6:I19"), 9, False)
        ElseIf WeekNumber > 27 And WeekNumber < 40 Then
            Hours(k) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(WeekNumber, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Eng_Availability_Report").Range("J6:K19"), 11, False)
        ElseIf WeekNumber > 40 And WeekNumber <= 53 Then
            Hours(k) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(WeekNumber, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Eng_Availability_Report").Range("L6:M19"), 13, False)
        End If
 Else
 ReDim Hours(LBound(Arr1()) - UBound(Arr1()))
 For i = LBound(Arr1()) To UBound(Arr1())
     WeekNumber = Int(((Arr1(i, 1) - DateSerial(Year(Arr1(i, 1)), 1, 0)) + 6) / 7)
        If WeekNumber > 0 And WeekNumber < 14 Then
            Hours(k) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(WeekNumber, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Eng_Availability_Report").Range("F6:G19"), 7, False)
        ElseIf WeekNumber > 14 And WeekNumber < 27 Then
            Hours(k) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(WeekNumber, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Eng_Availability_Report").Range("H6:I19"), 9, False)
        ElseIf WeekNumber > 27 And WeekNumber < 40 Then
            Hours(k) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(WeekNumber, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Eng_Availability_Report").Range("J6:K19"), 11, False)
        ElseIf WeekNumber > 40 And WeekNumber <= 53 Then
            Hours(k) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(WeekNumber, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Eng_Availability_Report").Range("L6:M19"), 13, False)
        End If
    k = k + 1
Next

End If

ReturnHoursPerWeek = Hours()

End Function
```

Comment: When it's executing the Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(Arg1,Arg2...). Couldn't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, you seem to be looking for column numbers such as 7 when you only have 2 columns (F:F-G:G). I would guess you need to change the ranges or decrease the incremental numbers.

At the moment, you are looking for a column outside of the array. Going by the letters you probably want to start at the root 'matching' cell and go 7/8/9 etc to the right and return the value. I'm presuming (going by the code) that the 'matching cell' is in the first column, so by changing the ranges so that the first column is always A, ending in the column you want. That should fix the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Would you mind extending the answer little bit more to explain how it helps to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks Trum, Daenarys, and pnuts. I was in front of the problem but i couldn't see. Everything is working now.

Comment: I've changed this thread as Solved, is this ok? Thanks again!